# Shopping cart price rule applied at Grand total (or subtotal after discount)

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, grand-total

I have a rule:

> Buy 2,500 get product A free

Then customer has coupon discount **200** and grand total now **2300**.
In this case rule **2500** must not be applied.

I've found on **shopping cart price rule** condition but there is no **grand total condition**. So how do I set up that rule applied at **grand total** (or subtotal after discount) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393617/magento-free-shipping-shopping-cart-rule-help-needed/16808826

Comment: The only way to do that with core functionality would be to use Shopping Cart Price Rule priority with an option to Disable All Other Promotions.

Comment: Hi @HungDQ could you  provide more details, like what version of Magento are you using? Thanks

Comment: My shopping cart price rule apply for subtotal, how can i change it to selected products?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Magento 1.x

This can be achieved by disabling **further rules processing** option in the promotion rule which gives 200 discount